# Get elements inside and outside table element in OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

How can I discriminate the elements inside a table and those outside? And additionally how can I verify tables without a content control name?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you using a particular library or SDK?  Are you working on the xml directly?

Comment: Haven't try anything successful yet.

This is my code
`tags = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().
                    Where(t=>t.Parent.LocalName=="tr").
                    Select(t => t.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val).ToList();`

But it's not right as I'm looking for Table parents and not tr and I need to verify that the Table parent is surrounded by a block element too.

I am using OpenXML 4.0 library.

Comment: Please edit your post to include what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Linq To XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx).  On MSDN there is an [example console application that displays all paragraph text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693147.aspx) of a Word Document.

Near the bottom is a comment - Find all paragraphs in the document - this is the [Linq To XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx) piece that pulls out the paragraphs from the body of the Word document.

```
// Find all paragraphs in the document.  
    var paragraphs =  
        from para in xDoc  
                     .Root  
                     .Element(w + "body")  
                     .Descendants(w + "p")  ...
```

Instead of a `"p"`, you will need to use `"tbl"`.  This is how to collect all of the tables from a Document in order to verify their contents.  To inspect each row and column will involve more code to loop through the tables data, but this should get you started.

If you install the Open XML Productivity Tool, you can view all of the xml of any Open XML document.  The screen below shows the tool with a Word doc containing a table.

[[image]]

The left pane show the structure of a typical table in a Word doc.  The right is the Open XML Table spec.  The tool helps you know what to read and what to ignore when you are writing your liq to xml code to read and verify the data in your tables.

If you have a specific table format you need to read for your project and you are stuck, post the table and the code you tried in another question.  Otherwise based on your original question, this answer should be enough to help you get started towards your solution.